# Why Grail App war file taking too much size compare to source code

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have created a grail application that has 8.9 MB but once i generate the war file size is showing 30 MB why its taking 30 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the WAR file is due to the libraries required for a Spring/Grails application.

Comment: how to remove those unwanted libraries

Answer (score 0):

This is reason :

Grails is a mix of many frameworks, spring, hibernate etc. All the frameworks are included and you need them as they are the baseline of grails
every grails application comes with many plugins by default (look into your BuildConfig.groovy):
 cache, asset, scaffolding etc. Every plugin has their own dependencies like classes, jars, js etc All of them add up.

Solution: a war and also a jar are just containers. Open them with your favorite unzip program and check.

You can remove that by using following command

```
grails war -nojars
```

Note: It will build a war without WEB-INF/lib jars. But you have to provide them to your webserver before deployment.

reference: http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/05/create-much-smaller-grails-war-file.html

OR

If you want remove the perticular jar files then you can use below config

Add to your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/whatever.jar")
}
```